# Camel Apache: can I use a retryWhile to re-send a request?

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to achieve the following kind of orchestration with CAMEL:

1. Client sends a HTTP POST request to CAMEL
2. CAMEL sends HTTP POST request to external endpoint (server)
3. External server replies with a 200 OK
4. CAMEL sends HTTP GET request to external endpoint (server)
5. External server replies

After step 5, I want to check the reply: if the reply is a 200 OK and state = INPROGRESS (this state can be retrieved from the received XML body), I want to re-transmit the HTTP GET to the external endpoint until the state is different from INPROGRESS.

I was thinking to use the retryWhile statement, but I am not sure how to build the routine within the route.
Eg, for checking whether the reply is a 200 OK and state = INPROGRESS, I can easily introduce a Predicate. So the retryWhile already becomes like:

.retryWhile(Is200OKandINPROGRESS)

but where should I place it in the route so that the HTTP GET will be re-transmitted ?

Eg: (only taking step 4 and 5 into account)

```
from("...")
  // here format the message to be sent out
  .to("external_server")
      // what code should I write here ??
      // something like: 
      //     .onException(alwaysDo.class)
      //         .retryWhile(Is200OKandINPROGRESS)
      //         .delay(2000)
      //     .end ()
      // or maybe it should not be here ??
```

I am also a bit confused how the "alwaysDo.class" should look like ??
Or ... should I use something completely different to solve this orchestration ?
(I just want to re-transmit as long as I get a 200 OK with INPROGRESS state ...)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CAMEL Nabble, someone replied my question. Check out:

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-Apache-can-I-use-a-retryWhile-to-re-send-a-request-td5498382.html

By using a loop statement, I could re-transmit the HTTP GET request until I received a state different from INPROGRESS. The check on the state needs to be put inside the loop statement using a choice statement. So something like:

```
   .loop(60)
       .choice()
       .when(not(Is200OKandINPROGRESS)).stop()  // if state is not INPROGRESS, then stop the loop
   .end() // choice
       .log("Received an INPROGRESS reply on QueryTransaction ... retrying in 5 seconds")
       .delay(5000)
       .to(httpendpoint")   
    .end() //loop
```

Comment: In fact, when u use .stop() it will stop whole route, which might be undesirable. Imaging something like this:
`from("direct:foo")
 .to("direct:boo")
 .process(someProcessor());`

`from("direct:boo")
 .loop(100)
  .choice()
   .when(stopPredicate()).stop()
  .end()
 .end()
 .process(someOtherProcessor());`

The .stop() will cause, that someProcessor() and someOtherProcessor() will not be invoked. And this might be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

I never experimented what you are trying to do but it seems does not seem right.
In the code you are showing, the retry will only occur when an alwaysDo Exception is thrown.

The alwaysDo.class you are refering to should be the name of the Java Exception class you are expecting to handle. See http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html for more details.

The idea should be to make the call and inspect the response content then do a CBR based on the **state** attribute. Either call the GET again or terminate/continue the route.

Comment: Hi Oliver, already thanks for the reply. Problem with using the CBR and calling the GET again, is that I do not know how often I would need to do this ... I just want to do it until I get a different response than INPROGRESS ... a kind of "do while" in fact ...

Comment: Almost forgot to mention: I currently made a kind of 'dummy' alwaysDo.class, so that I would always end up with the exception ... I could be quite wrong there too :( ... sorry, I am rather a novice in programming here ...

Comment: In my mind this is someting you can do with a CBR (<http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html>. Since it allows you to  perform an action based on the content of your exchange (or properties). You could inspect the state attribute and perform either the GET again, if state=INPROGRESS or continue the route if state != INPROGRESS. However, you might probably want to have other condition to exit the loop in case the server is not available for instance (avoiding an infinite loop). I do not really see what you put in your alwaysDo class, could you provide it?

Comment: Hi Olivier, I am rather looking for a kind of polling mechanism: keep on sending GET messages as longs as they get returned with an INPROGRESS state ... once another state gets returned, I want to get out of the polling.

Comment: So you would like to initiate the route somehow (from) then do some stuff. After doing the rest of the processing you need to wait for a given signal (state!=INPROGRESS). This means the poller would only be active during a specific moment in the route. Is that right ?

Comment: Not really. Scenario is: CAMEL sends HTTP GET request, server replies 200 OK, state = INPROGRESS. So, CAMEL should re-attempt. As long as the server replies with 200 OK, state = progress, CAMEL re-attempts. Finally, the server sends a 200 OK with another state, the route can continue. (of course, we could consider to set the max. retries to 5 or 10 attempts)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should write a message to [the Apache Camel mailing list](http://camel.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) (or via [Nabble](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-Users-f465428.html)) . Commiters are watching it and are very reactive.

Comment: Ok, posted on Camel nabble: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-Apache-can-I-use-a-retryWhile-to-re-send-a-request-td5498382.html

Comment: I guess that I am also completely wrong about the use of OnException ... as I do not really have an Exception here ... (sorry, but I am not really a Java programmer :() ... Just wondering whether there is no other way to poll the server until I get another state back than INPROGRESS ...

Comment: That is also what I think. What you are trying to do is a do ... while loop. Maybe you could use the loop pattern (http://camel.apache.org/loop.html) that allows you to repeat an action until a given condition is met (use non copy mode). You could perform the HTTP GET on each iteration and test the state to decide if you need another iteration.